# How to call method as a property in Python?

Tags: python, class, object, methods, properties

Let's say I've got a class representing a user:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__():
        self.first_name = 'Mr'
        self.last_name = 'Anderson'
    def name():
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

with the `name` helper method I can easily get the full name:

```
>>> u = User()
>>> u.first_name
'Mr'
>>> u.name()
'Mr Anderson'
```

But the thing is that I don't want to call `name` as a method, but as a property. Is there a way that I can make it behave like this:

```
>>> u = User()
>>> u.name
'Mr Anderson'
```

Comment: The linked duplicate was the very first result when I pasted this question's title into a Google search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`@property`](http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property) decorator.

```
class User(object):
    def __init__():
        self.first_name = 'Mr'
        self.last_name = 'Anderson'

    @property
    def name():
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

If you are not familiar with [decorator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/), you have to know that these are functions or classes which wrap the methods or functions to which there are prepend.

So, using the `@property` decorator wraps your function into the class [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), and let you manipulate it as any attribute of your class.